# Sending Payments via QBO API

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Is it possible to send payments via Quickbooks Online API?

We are looking to basically initiate a ACH transfer from the QBO Client's bank account to another account, not just record a transaction.

Is this possible? If so via which API / Method? I have been looking all over the QB Documentation and can't find a clear answer. Support calls say it's possible but don't give any direction where to get stated.

I have already registered as a developer, created an app and have been able to implement authorization and tokens and manipulate basic QBO Data, jsut need to figure out where or how to send payments if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to send payments via Quickbooks Online API?

No.